# speedup ubuntu 16.04.2 boot process

Tags: boot, 16.04, partitioning

I have recently purchased a new lenovo thinkpad e470, which packs 8GB of RAM, 1TB of hard disk and an intel i5 7th gen processor.

I was expecting a optimum boot load time with this system configuration, but its taking 40sec to show login screen and 10sec to show applications after login.

I have referred many related questions and these are all different logs I got from my system.

I installed ubuntu by selecting '**Erase and install ubuntu**' option.

*systemd-analyze*

`Startup finished in 4.582s (kernel) + 21.345s (userspace) = 25.928s`

*systemd-analyze blame*

```
  16.382s dev-sda5.device
  9.707s networking.service
  9.472s apport.service
  9.349s irqbalance.service
  9.306s speech-dispatcher.service
  9.164s preload.service
  9.145s grub-common.service
  9.029s ondemand.service
  7.936s accounts-daemon.service
  7.837s ModemManager.service
  6.792s alsa-restore.service
  6.779s gpu-manager.service
  6.777s pppd-dns.service
  6.777s rsyslog.service
  6.758s avahi-daemon.service
  6.588s systemd-logind.service
  6.559s systemd-user-sessions.service
  6.537s thermald.service
  6.052s apparmor.service
  4.130s console-setup.service
  2.526s lightdm.service
  1.288s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
  1.143s systemd-udevd.service
  1.135s keyboard-setup.service
  1.047s NetworkManager.service
  1.041s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
```

*systemd-analyze critical-chain*

```
graphical.target @21.325s
└─multi-user.target @21.325s
  └─apport.service @11.852s +9.472s
    └─basic.target @11.616s
      └─sockets.target @11.616s
        └─snapd.socket @11.613s +1ms
          └─sysinit.target @11.436s
            └─swap.target @11.436s
              └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-366e2b36\x2d8a0d\x2d4faa\x2da967\x2db56208442065.swap @11.178s +257ms
                └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-366e2b36\x2d8a0d\x2d4faa\x2da967\x2db56208442065.device @11.176s
```

*dmesg* output [here](https://pastebin.com/8xJb5YPS).

*blkid*

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="366e2b36-8a0d-4faa-a967-b56208442065" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="c159dac6-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="b04418b9-5cd3-4cee-ac32-fedd8e275fde" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="c159dac6-02"
/dev/sda5: UUID="1370c811-80ca-4045-9e4d-c5496496502a" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="c159dac6-05"
```

And my */etc/fstab* file is as bellow.

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=1370c811-80ca-4045-9e4d-c5496496502a /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=366e2b36-8a0d-4faa-a967-b56208442065 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

I have also modified below files to give a try

- `/etc/default/grub` modified `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10` to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=3`
- `/etc/systemd/system.conf` modified `DefaultTimeoutStartSec=10s
  DefaultTimeoutStopSec=10s`

Still I am not able to get any boot load time improvements. Can anyone suggest me how to improve boot load?

Comment: It doesn't look like anything is out of the ordinary. 50 seconds may not be a speed record, but it's also not catastrophic. Fast or slow is very subjective, and sometimes, the only way to get optimal boot times is to adjust one's own expectations.

Comment: does that mean, for this configuration ~50 sec is optimum boot time?

Comment: Looks normal, boot-time varies, sometime file-systems are checked during boot, sometime not.

Comment: IMHO, yes, it's quite alright for a PC with an HDD of probably 5400 rpm. Had there been an SSD, I would have expected faster boot times. It is not uncommon these days to put the OS on an SSD, and use an HDD for data.

Comment: In `terminal` type `sudo fdisk -l` and see if it tells you that any of your disk partitions are misaligned.

Comment: `sudo fdisk -l` shows me `Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1          2048    7999487    7997440   3.8G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda2  *    7999488    8976383     976896   477M 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       8978430 1953523711 1944545282 927.2G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       8978432 1953523711 1944545280 927.2G 83 Linux

Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.`

Answer (score 0):

My computer is 7 years old Lenovo G560 Intel i5, 8gb ram, 120 gb Samsung SSD disk. SSD is connected to old Sata 2 interface. Write speed is about 100 MB/s. I'm using XUbuntu 16 and boot speed is about 15 seconds, shutdown speed is about 5 seconds. If you use SSD disk your boot time will decrease.

And I'm using /tmp folder in RAM. Add this line to /etc/fstab and restart your system then your boot and shutdown times must be decrease.

```
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,noatime,nosuid,nodev,exec,mode=1777,size=1024M 0 0
```

And this site may help some issues about that how to tweak ubuntu:

https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/speed

[How to speed up your boot on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/826819/how-to-speed-up-your-boot-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: didn't improved any boot time! Thanks for the links.

Comment: Don't forget to remove unnecessary services and startup applications.

Comment: taken care of unnecessary services and startup applications.